# angular ssr authentication issue

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

the problem is how to authenticate user on server side?
i hear rapidly that authentication should done on client side using `isPlatformBrowser`.
but the problem is when user is login and then we send a request to the angular ssr, here rendering page is not correct, instead of seeing the correct page, user will see login page!
i'm wondering that no body mentioned this issue!!!
also infer 2 ways: 1: on the server side, we should request to the api server and get approve that user is valid or not.
2: we use cookie and check if there is a specific key in cookie on the authGuard

i want to know is there any other way that is better that mine?
and also want to know if i use cookie approach, is it safe just to check for its existing and no one other than api server can add it manually or not?

Comment: I have a same problem, did you resolve it? any update?

Comment: No, not yet, I will put it here if I find the way, I all ready do it with cookie. I will have some changes very soon.

Comment: Got the same issue.. In my case the authentication is not completed or even started and the AuthGuard already checks if it's good to go.. 

Looks like this:
- Enter url and hit enter
- Authguard check -> fails
- Redirect to login page
- Autologin function starts

If there is a permanent solution please let me know